# Referencing the outputs of a task in another project in Gradle

Tags: gradle

Consider the following setup

```
rootProject
|--projectA
|--projectB
```

There is a task `taskB` in `projectB` and I would like the reference the outputs of that task in a copy task `taskA` in `projectA`. For example, `taskA` might look something like:

```
task taskA(type: Copy) {    
    dependsOn ':projectB:taskB'

    from ':projectB:taskB.outputs'

    into 'someFolder'
}
```

Of course the above example doesn't actually work. While it's okay to reference the task as `:projectB:taskB` as a dependency, `:projectB:taskB.outputs` doesn't seem to mean anything to Gradle. I've tried reading through the Gradle docs but didn't find anything that referenced what I'm trying to do.

Comment: try `tasks(':projectB:taskB').outputs`

Comment: tried that and it throws an error at config time. also tried using `task(..)` and that didn't seem to do anything

Comment: I've learned that you can use `evaluationDependsOn(:projectB)` to have `projectA` depend on `projectB` already being configured. And then you can do something like `rootProject.project('projectB').tasks.getByName('taskB').outputs`

Comment: Slightly simpler, you can also do: `tasks.getByPath(':projectB:taskB').outputs`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

projectA build.gradle should be:

```
evaluationDependsOn(':projectB')

task taskA(type:Copy, dependsOn:':projectB:taskB'){
    from tasks.getByPath(':projectB:taskB').outputs
    into 'someFolder'
}
```

Comment: yup. this is basically what i ended up going with!

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer has been to only and recommended way to solve this problem. However building up this kind of project dependencies and reaching from one project into another is discouraged by the Gradle team now. Instead of this, projects should only interact with each others using publication variants. So the idiomatic (but sadly at the moment more verbose) way would be:

On the producing side (`projectB`) define a configuration that is not resolvable but consumable by other projects and creates a new variant (called `taskB-variant`)

```
configurations.create("taskElements") {
    isCanBeResolved = false
    isCanBeConsumed = true
    attributes {
        attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, project.objects.named(Usage::class, "taskB-variant"))
    }
    outgoing.artifact(taskB.outputs)
}
```

On the consuming side (`projectA`) define a configuration that is resolvable but not consumable for the same variant and define a dependency to `projectB`

```
val taskOutputs by configurations.creating {
    isCanBeResolved = true
    isCanBeConsumed = false
    attributes {
        attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, project.objects.named(Usage::class, "taskB-variant"))
    }
}

dependencies {
    taskOutputs(project(":projectB"))
}

tasks.register<Copy>("taskA") {
    from taskOutputs
    into 'someFolder'
}
```

This way you decouple how the outputs are produced and the publication variant (called "taskB-variant") becomes the interface between `projectA` and `projectB`. So whenever you change the way the output is created you only need to refactor `projectB` but not `projectA` as long as you make sure the outputs end up in the `taskElements` configuration.

At the moment this is still pretty verbose but hopefully Gradle will get more powerful APIs to describe this kind of project relationships in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is certainly more verbose, but the intention makes sense to me.

Comment: [Gradle docs reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/cross_project_publications.html) - it seems that specifying a variant is not essential.